# How to make time input HTML step 30 minute and hide seconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

How to make time input HTML ONLY step 30 minute and hide seconds and prevent user from entering any out of range numbers?

Comment: Could you please share your code/attempt? I'd suggest making a dropdown for minutes with values (30,00) and hour values (0..23). Check out HTML `select` tag.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs on dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) it's doable like this.

```
<label for="hr">Hour</label>
  <select name="hr" id="hr">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
<!-- do it for each hour -->
  </select>
  <br><br>

<label for="min">Minute</label>
  <select name="min" id="min">
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="00">00</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
```

You can also look into date/time picker libraries but it'd need some JS. Best is to stick with a dropdown with values you can control. Good luck